# Simple PHP script help, if/else/timestamps/ less than / bit-shift

Tags: php, timestamp, if-statement

I am trying to make a timestamp function that checks which displays a time if it has been less than 24 hours and a date if it has been more. If anybody knows of a prebuilt way to do this please let me know.

Anyways, I've started with this simple php which is suppose to return a number less than 86400 if $temprow1 or 2 are less than 86400 seconds from now, or echo full if it has been over a day. This code outputs both as numbers, which it should not. Can somebody please help me figure out what's wrong. Thanks!

```
$temprow1 = 1278867245;
$temprow2 = 1258567245;

$tempvar008 = time()-$temprow1;
$tempvar009 = time()-$temprow2;

if($tempvar008 << 86400){echo $tempvar008;}else{echo 'full';}
echo '<br>';
if($tempvar009 << 86400){echo $tempvar009;}else{echo 'full';}
```

Comment: Is the `<<` a typo? Otherwise, that's the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use a single `<` for less-than comparisons. `<<` is for bit-shifting.

Comment: ohhhhh, that's why in another script <= worked fine but not <<. I've always thought << meant less than. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `<<` is about in the context of an if, but try this:

```
$temprow1 = 1278867245;
$temprow2 = 1258567245;

$tempvar008 = time()-$temprow1;
$tempvar009 = time()-$temprow2;

if($tempvar008 < 86400){echo $tempvar008;}else{echo 'full';}
echo '</br>';
if($tempvar009 < 86400){echo $tempvar009;}else{echo 'full';}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stamp1 = 1234567890;
$stamp2 = 1234567891;
$stampd = $stamp2 - $stamp1;
if ($stampd < 86400) // code for showing time difference
else // code for showing date difference
```

To continue using your code instead, please replace `<<` with `<`.